# spoj - CPCRC1C, sum of digits of numbers 1 to n, need clarification, not solution

Tags: dynamic-programming

---

Once, one boy's teacher asked him to calculate the sum of numbers 1 through n.

the boy quickly answered, and his teacher made him another challenge. He asked him to calculate the sum of the digits of numbers 1 through n.

Input
Two space-separated integers 0 <= a <= b <= 109.

Output
The sum of the digits of numbers a through b.

Example
Input:
1 10

Output: 46

---

can someone explain what is meant by **sum of the digits of numbers a to b**?

from above, sum of {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 } is 55 , it is a well known Gaussian formula

but the output is 46!
if i count from 2 to 9, excluding the border numbers 1 and 10,  the answer is 44 , still not 46

So what is meant by sum of digits of numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + (1 + 0)
```

Don't treat the `10` as the number `10`, rather the digits `1` and `0`